# HighChart Tooltip word-break issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

I searched a lot but i am not finding any suitable solution to my problem. I am using HighChart plugins to create pie chart as well as bar chart.

My problem is, after hovering on any bar chart or pie chart default tool-tip appears, in that i want to use css property  **word-break** & **white-space** in that tooltip. Right now the text getting cut if it goes outside of container width.

I tried overwriting the **.highcharts-tooltip** css but is not working.
See in example, hover on blue & black slice you will get to know the issue i am facing.

```
.highcharts-tooltip {
word-break: break-word !important;    
white-space: normal !important;
```

}

Here is   [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6mk3S/107/)

Any help is Appreciated.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to customize your tooltip like this you will have set the tooltip option useHtml to true:

```
tooltip: {
  useHTML: true
}
```

From Higcharts documentation:

> **useHTML**: BooleanSince 2.2
>
> Use HTML to render the contents of the tooltip instead of SVG. Using HTML 
>   allows advanced formatting like tables and images in the tooltip.

Then you need to set the CSS attribute to the *span* element of the .highcharts-tooltip (I also added a fixed width):

```
.highcharts-tooltip span {
   width: 140px;
   white-space:normal !important;
}
```

Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hz1tw94L/)

Answer (score 1):

Just enable the `useHTML` property for the tooltip and you can style your own tooltip (incl. `word-break` and `white-space`.

```
tooltip: {
    useHTML: true,
  formatter: function() {
    return "<div class='tooltip-key'><span>" + this.key + "</span></div>"
  }
},
```

Check out the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jorrex/L4t6bjac/1/) or run the snippet below

```js
$(function() {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false,
            type: 'pie'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Browser market shares January, 2015 to May, 2015'
        },
        tooltip: {
         useHTML: true,
          formatter: function() {
           return "<div class='tooltip-key'><span>" + this.key + "</span></div>"
          }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                showInLegend: false,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Brands',
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: [{
                name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer Microsoft Internet Explorer Microsoft Internet Explorer Microsoft Internet Explorer Microsoft Internet Explorer Microsoft Internet Explorer Microsoft Internet Explorer Microsoft Internet Explorer',
                y: 56.33
            }, {
                name: ' Chrome  Chrome Chrome Chrome Chrome Chrome Chrome Chrome Chrome Chrome Chrome Chrome Chrome Chrome Chrome',
                y: 24.03,
                sliced: true,
                selected: true
            }, {
                name: 'Firefox',
                y: 10.38
            }, {
                name: 'Safari',
                y: 4.77
            }, {
                name: 'Opera',
                y: 0.91
            }, {
                name: 'Proprietary or Undetectable',
                y: 0.2
            }]
        }]
    });
});
```

```css
.tooltip-key {
  width: 300px;
  word-break: break-word;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharttable.org/master/jquery.highchartTable-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

**Source**: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/tooltip#formatter